# Add Share button next to Like and Comment on Facebook Post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I'm using Facebook's Feed Dialog:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Whenever I post something using it, Facebook adds 2 links at the bottom (Like and Comment):

[image]

However, when I see other posts in the Timeline, I also see a "Share" link as well:

[image]

How can I instruct Facebook to also add this "Share" link through the feed dialog?

Comment: Looks like that you can't share your post ). Because you have already "shared" it. Try to check it from other account.

Comment: Hi RredCat, that's not it. I've tested this numerous times and the "Share" link never appears for me. I'm getting bug reports from my app users because of this.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Check it once, whether its is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have share link for feed posts from an application but you can have for link posts as Explained in second example. Or You can also add action links to a post message like this.

```
FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
     link: 'http://venu.com/',
     picture: 'http://venu.com/f8.jpg',
     caption: 'Venu site',
     description: 'asdasdasdasd.',
     message: 'asdasdasd!',
    actions: [
        { name: 'share', link: 'link here' }
      ]

   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
```

Link will be to a custom page in your site/app. Since user is trying to share the messages which was posted by some body else, you should have the message in your server. You can pass the id of the message in the custom URl.

Hope this helps you :)

**[EDIT]**

or

You can add a link with share button you have to use 'me/links' instead of 'me/feed'. Unfortunately this isnt a complete replacement as Facebook ignores the description, title and picture parameters when using this method. this is bug posted here.(https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/194522957295380)

```
$attachment = array(
    'access_token'=>TOKEN_HERE,
    'message'=>'message_here',
    'link' => 'http://www.example.com/',
);

$result = $facebook->api(
    'me/links',
    'post',
    $attachment
);
```

So, now this is similar to having a like button in your site. Facebook pulls the information from open graph meta tags in the given link.

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="name for ENTIRE SITE"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="name of PAGE"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="website"/>
    <meta property="og:image" content="<URL HERE>"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="my description" />
    <title>Untitled</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks for this informative response.  The 'actions' parameter is one that I explored, but the best I can come up with is setting the name to 'Share' and link to the Sharer (e.g. http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u={url}). Unfortunately: 1) this link redirects the user to the Sharer page, which isn't as nice as the native pop-up.  2)for posts on Facebook Page Timeline, the 'action' links aren't inline with comment/like, which makes it hard to find.  I'll give your me/links option a try, but the limitations will most likely be a problem for my situation.

Comment: You are welcome. If you are going to use the me/links, facebook will pull the information from the link (openrgaph meta tags). I would suggest you to have a look at this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/

With this, you can escape from the bug which I mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 4):

Posts that have the Share option are native posts, not application posts. Your post has the "via Careers, Jobs and Recruitment App", meaning it's an application post. For you to have the native "Share" option, you'd have to use a native post, which involves using [sharer.php](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) (see "Creating your own Share URL" near the bottom).

Comment: Thanks Jimmy.  I was afraid of this, but I think you're right.  Unfortunately, the Sharer has been deprecated.  It would be trivial for Facebook to add a native "Share" button just like they do to native posts.  I'm not sure why they don't.

Comment: @JohnnyO the share **button** has been deprecated, but you can still fire a popup to `sharer.php` (via `window.open`) to trigger a native share. Hundreds of sites all over the web use this, so I don't think it'll be deprecated soon, but if it is, at least you're in the same boat as everyone else. :)

Comment: thanks.  Using Sharer is still a problem for me, as I do the posting server-side so that the user is able to post to Facebook/Twitter/LinkedIn at once.  The best option I can come up with is to use the feed dialog with the action parameter (as Venu Gopal T describes) and set the link to the Sharer.  Unfortunately, once posted on Timeline, my "Share" hack button doesn't work as nicely as the native one.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Like Button social plugin is nearly the same as using the Sharer.php method, and is the currently supported replacement for Share buttons.

If you have a web page, when a user clicks the "Like" button, they will post a link to their wall which will have a "Share" link in it.

You could do something similar within a canvas app, although this wouldn't work for Feed posts that need dynamic text, such as the user's name or some value from their actions in the app.