# Facebook Share Icon not visible for posts made through Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem with posting updates to facebook through graph API,when i post something to facebook through graph API, only like and comment are shown for that update in facebook and no share icon, after a little googling i found out that we should use **me/links** as end point while posting and that's working great i can see share icon for all the link updates i am making now but the problem is how should i handle the case for normal text updates without any links in them how should i post such updates in order to get share icon in facebook,

below is the code i am using for link updates,it posts the update and i can see the share icon in facebook

```
facebookClient.publish("me/links", String.class , inputStream, 
            Parameter.with(ACCESS_TOKEN_PARAM,  accessToken), Parameter.with(MESSAGE, message), 
            Parameter.with(PICTURE, imageURL), Parameter.with(LINK, link==null?"":link));
```

and below is the code i am using to post text updates this code posts the update but with no share icon in facebook.

```
facebookClient.publish("me/feed", String.class ,
            Parameter.with(ACCESS_TOKEN_PARAM,  accessToken), Parameter.with(MESSAGE, message));
```

Comment: Check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558080/add-share-button-next-to-like-and-comment-on-facebook-post/10586311#10586311

Comment: Thanks Venu, i checked your answer i used me/links method it works fine for link updates made through graph api i am able to see share icon in facebook, but my question is how to post normal text updates without any links.I tried by passing the link parameter as null/empty it didnt work.. any idea on that??

Comment: simply you cannot get share link for text updates from graph API. you have to use action link as I suggested in my answer in another post give above

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not a feature of the Graph API unfortunately. There is a feature request report [here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/164888633588257) that I would recommend you support by voting for it.

As a workaround, you should consider using an Open Graph Action with a user message as opposed to a stream publish call as it will show the Share link and other custom action links can be included too.